# Setting Up Devise AddDeviseToUsers Migration Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, installation, migration

While setting up devise, I ran into the following error:

```
== 20141006184828 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: name: ALTER TABLE "users"  
ADD "name"    varchar(255)/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/sqlite3-  
1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

I found a few different responses but none seemed to resolve my issue. I tried commenting out name in:

```
change_table(:users) do |t|

  t.string :name
```

but that only moved the problem down the line (i.e. complaining about adding duplicate e-mail column, etc.)... not sure where the root of the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally added two migrations which both add name/email to your DB. Go through all the migrations and make sure that you have only added `:name` and `:email` once.

If you are still getting an error then try:

```
rake db:reset
```

This will drop your DB, re-create your DB and then run all your migrations. If this command returns the same error then you know there must be something wrong with your migrations, there must still be a duplicate in there somewhere.